# With same values we build AVL and B-Tree, number of steps difference

Tags: algorithm, tree, avl-tree, b-tree

With **same values** we build AVL and B-Tree, Is it possible that for a certain random of steps of searching a value in both trees, **the numbers of steps finding that value in the AVL tree will be LESSER than in the B-Tree?**

Comment: I think so. E.g. if the value sought happens to be the value of the root node in the AVL tree. I don't believe that same value is guaranteed to also be in the root of a corresponding B-tree.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thats true. Thank you!